# What makes search application download real content for crawling?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, database, crawl

I have a Windows Server 2012 server with SharePoint Foundation 2013 and the latest CU from September 17.
This front end server is connected to a sql 2008 r2 server.
I have 4 sharepoint applications created.
My issues is with one of them because it stores PDF files, many....about 800000 documents....not yet one million. Although there are many files in there, the database is only about 60GB.

People started to complain that they could not use search because it was not working. I found out that I was out of disk space on the sharepoint server and a crawl was running.

I stop the crawl and I've got my disc space back. Started another crawl and the disk space was gone again...basically I cannot do a crawl on this because it takes all the disk space. I extended the disk space to 800GB and it was not enough as well. It seems that crawl is really pulling the real content from database instead of crawling just a link or so. It's not behaving normally or according to expected. We have a bigger database with about 800GB and also many files and it doesn't behave like this.

Any suggestions? This is freaking me out for a long time now. I have installed new servers and all and I always get the same result.

Your help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Aganju.

Comment: Every piece of content needs to be scraped, so I don't know what you feel 'normal' is. A file must be downloaded by the crawler to go through the pipeline and have it entered into the index.

Comment: Seems about right, the index tends to be about 10-20% of the size of the corpus.

Comment: So you're saying that is normal that a 60Gb database needs about 2 TB of free disk space to perform a full crawl, is that it?

Comment: No, the number should be closer to 10-20% of the total (30-40% before a merge is completed). The problem is that you have crashed the index a few times and there are probably corrupt files left behind. I don't work with Foundation Search (ever) so I could not say for sure, but you may want to try resetting your index and then performing a full crawl to rebuild the index, watching for your disk space issues.